# Unable to mount NTFS hard drive partition "The disk contains an unclean file system"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, ntfs

I have dual booted ubuntu 13.10 and windows 8.1 in my laptop.
Earlier my window partition(C drive)  and other NTFS partition was accessible from ubuntu.

Now its giving me this error and not mounting:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/waqar/120ABDC90ABDAA5D: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/waqar/120ABDC90ABDAA5D"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

C drive(window partition) is giving this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/waqar/BAD4D962D4D92185: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/waqar/BAD4D962D4D92185"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I have restarted my system, booted in windows and then again shut down the system properly but its continuously giving me the same error.

Any help?

Comment: [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)