# failed to mount HDD

Tags: mount, ntfs, hibernate

Comes with this message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/ubuntu/8686DD7986DD6A67:
Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=999,gid=999,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda2" "/media/ubuntu/8686DD7986DD6A67"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. Failed to mount '/dev/sda2': Operation not permitted The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

What do I type into the CLI, I just need to access the drive to backup the data?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same problem to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439634/unable-to-mount-ntfs-hard-drive-partition-the-disk-contains-an-unclean-file-sys). Can you boot into that Windows partition at all? If you can, boot into Windows and then just make sure you properly shut it down and then try again.

If you can't boot into that Windows partition it looks like [ntfsfix](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix) would be your next best option. To use ntfsfix you would have to install it and then run `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2`.

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: Windows not booting up at all :(
I cant seem to install ntfsfix?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Try running `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g`. If it says that it is already installed then just try run `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda2`