# Problem accessing Windows 8.1 drive from Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: windows-8, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I have a Toshiba Satellite Pro C50 laptop which came with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 (64 bit) alongside Windows as a dual boot system. However, I can't access any of my data on the Windows drive C which has the name TI3125550PA from Ubuntu.  I get the following error message:

```
Unable to access “TI3125550PA”
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/malcolm/TI3125550PA: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/malcolm/TI3125550PA"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I had exited Windows properly with 'Shut Down', not 'Sleep' and did that several times.

From within Windows I ran 'chkdsk /f /r /x' which took some time to complete but reported that it had been 100% successful.

From within Ubuntu I used 'GParted' to check the partition which had Windows on.  It quickly completed the task, but still I get the same error message and am unable to access my data on the Windows drive.

Any ideas?

Comment: " Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)" is pretty clear advice to me. Do that please. "I had exited Windows properly with 'Shut Down'" means hibernate if bios uses "fast boot". So this is 2-fold: turn off fast boot; reboot twice and then use Ubuntu to mount the windows disk.

Comment: dupe: http://askubuntu.com/questions/439634/unable-to-mount-ntfs-hard-drive-partition-the-disk-contains-an-unclean-file-sys and http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Extra info on fast boot: http://askubuntu.com/questions/452071/why-disable-fast-boot-on-windows-8-when-having-dual-booting

Comment: I checked that fast boot was disabled, boot speed is normal.  Still no go.  Tried to reinstall ubuntu, now after installation it boots into windows.  Oh dear!  Not a good day!  I very much appreciate your help though.